# Explicit Loading nested related models in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 project using EF6. I have 3 models: user, role and permission.

The relation between user and role is many to many. The relation between role and permission is many to many.

**LazyLoadingEnabled** is **disabled** in the database context.

```
public class Permission
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class TaskManagerDB : DbContext
{
    public TaskManagerDB() : base()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

At an earlier point, I fetch a given user:

```
User user = db.Users.Find(1);
```

**Now**: since I already have the model, how can I load the user roles with their permissions?

I have tried:

```
db.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.Roles).Query().Include(y => y.Permissions).Load();
```

But it's not working - `user.Roles` is still `null`.

The following solution is not acceptable because I already have the user Model:

```
User user = db.Users.Include("Roles.Permissions").Where(x => x.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you have tried

```
db.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.Roles).Query()
    .Include(y => y.Permissions)
    .Load();
```

is indeed the intended way. And it works for everything else except the many-to-many relationship with implicit junction table, which is the case here.

I don't know if it's a bug or "by design", but the solution is to `Include` the other (calling) end of the relationship, e.g.

```
db.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.Roles).Query()
    .Include(y => y.Users) // <--
    .Include(y => y.Permissions)
    .Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting the roles and permissions for a user:

```
db.Roles.Include("Permissions").Where(r => r.Users.Select(u => u.ID).Contains(user.ID));
```